# How to apply a trained neural network to write outputs into a csv file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have the following dataset,`data_num`, on which I have trained the neural network, here is sample of `data_num`:

```
    A   B   C   D  Label1
0  95  91   3  10       9
1  91  95   4   3       9
2  68  65  31  31       6
3  50  43  51  58       4
4   8   4  93  97       0
5  16  20  81  90       1
6  75  79  28  26       7
7  74  76  27  22       7
8  45  46  56  57       4
9   5   7  97  93       0
```

Here's the entire code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from IPython.core.display import display
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

data_num = pd.read_csv('mult_test.csv')

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
features = data_num.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(features))
scale_num_data = pd.concat([data_num['Label1'], features], axis=1)


dtrain, dtest = train_test_split(scale_num_data, test_size=0.25, random_state=570)
X = dtrain.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
y = dtrain['Label1']
Xtest = dtest.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
ytest = dtest['Label1']


model = Sequential([
    Dense(10, input_shape=(4, ), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)


scores = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, batch_size=5)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Now that the network is trained, I would like to apply the code to a new dataset, `predict_num` and print the NN output into a new column 'Predictions'. Here's a sample of the new dataset:

```
  Stock   A   B    C   D  Prediction
0  AMCX  46  43   57  52           
1  ABAC  83  86   11  18           
2  AKAM  55  52   45  43           
3   ACW  96  99    9   8           
4  AOLS  46  43   54  52           
5  ABAX   9   9  100  95           
6  AMTX   9   1   91  97           
7  ABMC  73  79   29  25           
8   ALE  58  56   50  44           
9  AMAT   8   1   98  92
```

`predict_num` also has an extra column 'Stock', so I would like to specify the features only as columns [A, B, C, D] and fill the column 'Predictions' with the output of the NN.

The final dataset should look like this:

```
  Stock   A   B    C   D  Prediction
0  AMCX  46  43   57  52           4
1  ABAC  83  86   11  18           8
2  AKAM  55  52   45  43           5
3   ACW  96  99    9   8           9
4  AOLS  46  43   54  52           4
5  ABAX   9   9  100  95           0
6  AMTX   9   1   91  97           0
7  ABMC  73  79   29  25           7
8   ALE  58  56   50  44           5
9  AMAT   8   1   98  92           0
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [model.predict](http://keras.io/models/model/#predict)

```
.... your code ....
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

pred = model.predict(xtest)
xtest["prediciton"] = pred
xtest.to_csv("my_new_file.csv")
```

:)

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to specify the A,B,C,D columns as I won't be necessarily using the xtest but another dataset with the 'Stock' column in it? Once again, thank you for your reply!

Comment: yeah! do you just want to change the column names? or get rid of them altogether?

Comment: No. Notice the first dataset only has the feature columns. But the second one has a 'Stock' column as well which is not a feature. Therefore, for the prediction, I want to specify [A, B, C, D] as features.

Comment: The reason for this is that the 'Stock' column is not important for training, but for the prediction I want to know which stock belongs to which features and the respective NN output in 'Predictions'.

Comment: keras isn't going to allow stock as an input. you can make 'Stock' a series and add it as the index to your final dataframe before printing

Comment: I understand, which is why I would specify only columns [A, B, C, D] as features and 'Stocks' would be ignored.

Comment: There's no api that does that in the documentation.... I haven't any undocumented either https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py

Comment: Okay. Well thank you anyways because I've managed to find a work around. I can just merge 'Stocks' back to their respective features from a separate DataFrame based on one of the feature columns.

Comment: After running the code, I have encountered the following error: xtest["prediciton"] = pred
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1
Do you have any idea what to do with that?